# How get a shortcode working in category description

Tags: shortcode, categories

I want to use a shortcode for a table in a category description. It's my understanding that WP does not support this. I searched google and found some codes that i needed to add to the `functions.php`. But it's not working for me. What should I do?

Site/page: http://www.masflamenco.nl/category/flamencoles-utrecht/

Comment: This may help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175752/how-to-create-a-shortcode-to-display-a-category-description

Answer (score 3):

adding those codes into functions.php (tested in a child theme of Twenty Sixteen) seems to work:

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
```