# How to enable custom Shortcodes in Post Category Description?

Tags: posts, categories

I created a custom shortcode from my child theme's functions.php, And I want that shortcode to display in Post Category Description. But it's not working.

Do you guys have an idea on how to enable display of shortcodes in post category description?

[image]

Just correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question.

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
```

I just added those line of codes into the Child theme's function.php.

Thanks to this post: [How to get a shortcode working in category description](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232411/how-get-a-shortcode-working-in-category-description/232418#232418)

Comment: OK, so your question is a duplicate ;)

Comment: Yeah maybe. I noticed so I guess  I will just delete my post :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of code is using in your theme. I am sharing the code for idea.

```
$cat_desc = category_description();

echo do_shortcode( $cat_desc );
```

[category_description()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/) function is getting the a category description. do_shortcode() function is searching the content for shortcodes and filter shortcodes through their hooks.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your effort. I'm using Divi Theme with a Child Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Divi theme but I got a filter. You try this code

```
add_filter( "category_description", "wse_parse_shortcode" );
function wse_parse_shortcode( $value ) {
   return do_shortcode( $value );
}
```

category_description filter is defined in [**sanitize_term_field**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_term_field/) function